# Accept only numeric input

Tags: ruby

I want to force user to enter only numeric value from console. Below is my piece of code that is supposed to do that.

```
puts "Enter numeric value: "
result = gets.chomp

if result.to_i.is_a? Numeric
  puts "Valid input"
else
  puts "Invalid input."
end
```

It prints `Valid input` even if I enter a string value. And the reason is that every string has some equivalent numeric value in Ruby. Can someone help me fix the condition properly so that when user enters a non-numeric value, the script prompts `Invalid input.`?

Comment: Is "numeric" the right word? `(1.3).kind_of? Numeric #=> true`.

Comment: Pay no attention to requests from members who quickly post an answer and ask that you select it. Quick selections can discourage other answers and imo is disrespectful to those still working on their answers. If you've not selected an answer after a day or two, you might get a gentle reminder to select an answer if you found any of them helpful. Nothing wrong with that. The point is there's no rush to select (just don't forget). In case you don't know, as the asker, you can upvote or downvote answers, and can always change your selection of the answer you liked most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regular expressions, like this:

```
puts "Enter numeric value: "
result = gets

if result =~ /^-?[0-9]+$/
    puts "Valid input"
else
    puts "Invalid input."
end
```

The example above allows only digits [0..9].
If you want to read not only integers, you can allow a dot as well: `^-?[0-9]+$/`. Read more about regexp in Ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html

Comment: Feel free to mark it as an answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Keep in mind that `result` will still be a string after the conditional. Not sure what behavior you want but you may still need to convert it using `Integer(result)` or `result.to_i`

Comment: He can just type `result = result.to_i` after printing the message, am I right, bro? Or even `Integer(result)` because it won't throw any exception if it is already valid integer input.

Comment: Yes. After this check either `result.to_i` or `Integer(result)` would work. edited

Comment: Instead of `[0-9]` use `\d`. It's not as visually-noisy.

Comment: Since when [0-9] is visually-noisy? At least you know it is about the digits, not about the D.

Comment: This solution makes empty-strings valid input.

Answer (score 7):

[`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) will convert any string to an integer, even if it shouldn't:

```
"asdf".to_i
```

which returns `0`.

What you want to do is:

```
puts "Enter numeric value: "
result = gets.chomp

begin
  result = Integer(result)
  puts "Valid input"
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
  puts "Invalid input."    
  # handle error, maybe call `exit`? 
end
```

`Integer(some_nonnumeric_string)` throws an exception if the string cannot be converted to an integer, whereas `String#to_i` gives 0 in those cases, which is why `result.to_i.is_a? Numeric` is always true.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. I understood that part.  I needed help with having the correct `condition` in `if statement`?

Comment: You should use this to replace your entire conditional.

Comment: Of course you can also use regular expresion in your if statement if @cheniel's example is hard to understand for you. Check the answer below, both ways are working well tho.

Comment: @cheniel - Thank you for the example and explanation. I am using regular expression for now. But being a newbie it is good to know multiple solutions.

Comment: To me, the value in this example is that it uses an exception. Anyone coming from Python should feel at home with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean integer by "numeral", then:

```
puts "Enter numeric value: "
result = gets.chomp
case result
when /\D/, ""
  puts "Invalid input"
else
  puts "Valid input."
end
```

It also takes care of empty strings, which would be turned into `0` by `to_i`, which you probably do not want.