# How to detect numerical value of a text?

Tags: ruby, text, nlp, sentiment-analysis

We have data for survey question (e.g. rate us between 1-5) that's supposed to be numerical. However, we find that the response also includes

- repeated 5 times
- ❤️ repeated 4 times
- Great!
- four
- 3 and a half

I'd like a way to turn the user response into a numerical value. e.g. the text above should translate into 5, 4, 5, 4, 3.5 respectively. Obviously this won't work 100% of the time so I'm looking for an optimal solution (perhaps a text analysis approach) that gets me over 80%.

Answer (score 0):

If you are solely looking to turn THESE SPECIFIC responses into numerical values, then you can pass them through a series of if statements in a function:

```
    def inputToNumber(string)
        #thumbs up emoji
        if string == "\u{1f44d}"
            return 5
        #the word four
        elsif string == "four"
            return 4
        #etc., etc. with if statements for your other cases
        end
    end
```

But it might make more sense for you to only allow numeric answers to begin with, because:

1. You can't predict every possible written response
2. Someone could input malicious code

You didn't provide your code to show how you are accepting input so I can't really offer you specific solutions, but you can look here for some suggestions: [Accept only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146970/accept-only-numeric-input)

Good luck with your project.

Comment: These answers are coming via text/sms so we have no control. I'm looking for a text analysis approach that would yield these results. Doesn't have to be 100% correct but work for most cases. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I did a Google search for "ruby gem sentiment analysis" and got this link. You may want to take a look and also try a similar search. https://github.com/7compass/sentimental/blob/master/README.md