# I'm trying to convert a value to an integer what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm just trying to make this code work and I keep getting:

> <=': comparison of String with 21 failed (ArgumentError)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm learning and I've gone through every iteration of the code I can think of to try and make it work, I'm just not sure what I've done wrong.

```
puts "How old are you?"
old = gets.chomp

if old <= 21
  return "You are not legally allowed to buy alcohol in the US"
else 
  return "You are legally allowed to buy alcohol in the US"
end
```

Comment: If `old.to_i <= 21`. `gets.chomp.to_i` is the same as `get.to_i`.

Comment: _"I'm trying to convert a value to an integer"_ – you seem to be aware that you have to convert the input value to an integer. But no conversion occurs in your code. You're comparing the unconverted input to the integer 21 and Ruby tells you that it can't compare a string with `21` that way.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have to use `to_i` to convert the string into an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is correct but more verbosely, here is the line you need to change in your code:

```
old = gets.chomp.to_i
```

But you might also want to make sure user only enters an integer because calling `.to_i` on non-numeric characters will return `0`.

You might want to look at  [Accept only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146970/accept-only-numeric-input)

Comment: No need for `chomp`.

Comment: _"here is the line you need to change […] you might also want to make sure user only enters an integer"_ – nitpicking, but if you put the `to_i` right there, you can't check for non-integers anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try/improve as needed:

```
input = gets.chomp

if(val = Integer(input) rescue false)
  val < 21 ? 'Not old enough' : 'The usual martini?'
else
  'You did not provide an age (number)'
end
```

It checks if the input is an Integer, so it accounts for an input like `foo`.

Hth...

Comment: You can use `Integer(input, exception: false)` in recent Ruby versions.